# How do i split and assign values in nested nodes using Assign/XSLT in BPEL SOA?

Tags: xslt, middleware, soa, assign, bpel

Input-:

```
<input>1,2,3</input>
```

1,2,3
values separated with ",".

Required output-:

```
<ABC>
  <AB>
    <result>1</result>
  </AB>
  <AB>
   <result>2</result>
  </AB>
  <AB>
   <result>3</result>
  </AB>
</ABC>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 1.0 solution. It makes use of a recursive named template. I'm unsure this could be done using a `match="text()"` template, thus avoiding the parameters passing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="str" />

    <xsl:if test="contains($str, ',')">
      <AB>
        <result><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($str, ',')" /></result>
      </AB>
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="substring-after($str, ',')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ABC>
      <xsl:call-template name="split">
        <xsl:with-param name="str" select="concat(input/text(), ',')" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </ABC>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 2 has a `tokenize` function which allows you to do this more concisely :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ABC>
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(input, ',')">
        <AB>
          <result><xsl:value-of select="." /></result>
        </AB>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ABC>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Fabian Pijcke, I'm using XSL 1.0 I have used that logic but getting the same element repeated. ex-:input 1,2,3 but output that I am getting is 1 only in each node.... rest of the thing is working fine. can you please help me out?

Comment: Oh indeed, I put `substring-before(., ',')` instead of `substring-before($str, ',')`. I fix that in the answer, sorry about it :-)